# Issues with flush function on PHP

Tags: php, nginx, plesk, flush

I want to use flush from php in order to display echo's for the purpose of making a textual progress bar, but no matter what I do all are displayed only after all the script is finished.

I use Plesk to host my site, with a PHP version "7.4.27 FPM application"

I do my tests with a basic code with a loop and a sleep it should be correct here it is:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
echo 'Begin ...<br />';
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    echo $i . '<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo 'End ...<br />';
?>
```

I tried to modify some settings in Plesk following advice on forums but none of them worked like having disabled

> gzip on nginx

and in

> php.ini "output_buffering = Off" and "zlib.output_compression = Off"

Would you have any solutions for me?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What progress are you trying to report with this? You might find it easier to implement a progress bar in JavaScript and use [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) to update it.

Comment: I do it but now I have an other issue, when I use Ajax to do a big task using

`$.ajax({
   url: 'url.php',
   async: true,
   success: function(reponse){
  //Traitement de la réponse
  console.log("L'opération est fini");
   }
});`

For example when I do a long operation my page will be frozen during the process do you have an idea how I can fix it? What i want it's to put the process to background task and continue to using my webpage, thanks in advance for your help all !